# PHP can’t read from, write to or create XML files- only when hosted

Tags: php, xml, hosting

I've been working on a website which I need to host for a project. My site has multiple PHP scripts which create, delete, read or edit XML files. I've encountered a perplexing problem- the site works perfectly when hosted locally, but if it's hosted externally, it doesn't seem to be able to interact with XML files at all. It acts as if no files exist, and fails to create new ones. I'm having the exact same issue with Hiroku and InfinityFree, which leads me to believe that it's me doing something wrong, beats me what. I'm using exactly the same file structure when hosting locally and online.

I'm having difficulty deciding what to post here, as I'm receiving no errors and the issue might even not be in the code, could be I've set something up wrong on the hosting services. I’m hoping one of you excellent people has seen a similar issue in the past!

Comment: How do you interface with your host? FTP? Is your FTP user the same as the user the webserver runs as? (Unlikely if it's a shared host.) Have you tried playing with the file permissions on the host? As a start, you might try setting the file permissions on the host to `777` and seeing if that works. Be warned, this may not be a good set of permissions to use forever in production, but it might help you see if file permissions are the issue.

Comment: The other thing is you say that the file structure is the same local and remote, but is it? Again, with shared hosting it might not be. As in the path that the webserver sees and the paths you see from your login might be different. In your code, are you using absolute paths (starting from `/`) or relative paths to your script files? Remember that you can use PHP's magic `__DIR__` constant to get the current path to the script file at runtime, to help you build relative paths.

Comment: So far, I've been lazy and uploaded the files directly through the web file manager (InfinityFree) and through Git (Hiroku). This site won't really need to expand or last. Should I definitely be using FTP for this?

Comment: No, no absolute need to use FTP. If the web file manager shows and lets you change permissions that is more than enough.

Comment: Many thanks. Problem persists with file permissions at `777`. As I understand it, `__DIR__` should be used in a format similar to this line from my code: `if(file_exists('__DIR__/../users/' . $username . '.xml'))`, but I may be wrong here as it's still the same issue?

Comment: `__DIR__` should be used outside a string, so the line would be `if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../users/' . $username . '.xml'))`

Comment: Corrected to that, still no dice. Local version is also working with the` __DIR__` and without. Advice very much appreciated. This is driving us crazy here...

Comment: Then sorry, I'm out of ideas. ... these XML files are in your web directories, yes? As in you should be able to access them at `http://your.domain/users/dave.xml`? Can you access them from the web?

Answer (score -1):

Well, this entire time I'd suspected the cause was something stupid, and I was right.

The folder had a capital letter in its name but the code used lowercase.

In disbelief it took me this long to find that...

Comment: Well, at least you made me giggle. Glad you found it.